# How can these games be removed from this list I have on Steam?

Tags: steam

When I click on "Show hidden icons", then the hidden Steam icon, I see a list of three items at the top of a drop down menu, from upper to down: Doctor Kvorak's Obliteration Game Demo, Team Fortress 2 and Pink Hour. I'd like to get as much of them removed from that list as possible. How can I do that? I'm using Windows 10, just in case that'll help you answer my question.

Comment: When you click where? What hidden Steam icon? The list you have on Steam is personalized, so we need more information. Is it your Steam library?

Comment: No, it's not my Steam library.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you mean the '*Show hidden icons*' button ('^') on your Windows taskbar, and the Steam "quick menu":

[image: Steam menu as seen from the Windows 10 taskbar]

It shows the games you have recently played or acquired (I've not played *RobocraftX*, for example), so, **if you want to get rid of those specific items, try playing or downloading other games**.